# Can't install hadoop2.8.0 correctly

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, installation

I used Maven to install Hadoop 2.8.0,but it always says build failure.
Here's the error message:

> [ERROR]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy-resources) on project hadoop-build-tools: Cannot create resource output directory : ~/hadoop-build-tools/target/extra-resources -> [Help 1]

I checked help1 and it says **MojoExecutionException** is not generated by the Maven core itself but a plugin. It seems that the pom.xml needs to be corrected,but could you please help me how to revise it? Or any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml if you want us to revise it. Thanks

Comment: @BillF It's a really long file.Should post all of that?